# Parse: Download array in swift

Tags: arrays, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to search for data that contains a certain string then download an array from that row. I know how to do this in objective-c but not in swift. Here's the code I have to search for it:

```
let query = PFQuery(className:"Wait")
        query.whereKey("latitude", equalTo:self.latitude)
        query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
            (objects, error: NSError?) -> Void in

            if error == nil {

            }
        }
```

I'm not sure how to use "objects" to download the array from that row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make things more clear, this should be the closure signature:

```
query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
     (objects : [PFObject]?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
            if error == nil {

            }
     }
```

Then you can iterate through `objects` like:

```
for object in objects {
   print(object)
}
```

Comment: In the second part of the code, I can't find an object by `object.[columnname]`

Comment: Try using `object.objectForKey(columnname) as someType`

Comment: What do you mean by someType?

Comment: Well it could be any type, for example `Int` or `String`, depending on what type of data is in that column.